# Highstocks: Force panning to snap to value

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am using the Highstocks library from Highcharts.com to create a spline graph of multiple product values over a decade. Values are only plotted on the first of the month (when the data is published). Using the comparison technique, I can slide the graph on the xAxis and have the lines drawn as percent comparisons based on the minimum xAxis data value (i.e. price compared to 1st of July 2011). The problem is that the minimum xAxis value could be the 12th of June. Therefore, even though the graphs are generated as comparisons to the data value on the 1st of July (the minimum xAxis data value shown), the xAxis minimum value is June 12th. See image:

[image: graph]

Is there any way to force the graph to snap to the 1st of the month when panning?

Thanks a lot!!
-Mark

Comment: Can't you feed chart with data only for a specific period? Panning is allowed to use for all data, not only part of it.

Comment: I have data for the period of 10 years by month. Not sure what you mean by "feed chart with data only for a specific period". I just want the panning to snap to the first value to first of the month.